# how to get textbox value from ontextchanged event using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to get textbox value from their textchanged event using jquery/javascript. I tried many things but didnt work. The last is I try, Here is the following code

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.MaterialRecordRowCount; i++)
{
    <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" id="Material_PartNo@(i)" name="Material_PartNo@(i)" data-provide="typeahead"                 class="typeahead search-query form-control autocomplete" placeholder="PartNo" onclick="ShowData                 ('$('#Material_PartNo@(i)').val()')" />
                </div>
    </div>
}

function ShowData(PartNo) {
    alert(PartNo);
}
```

Now when I run this code it shows an error i.e. **Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token**

I am not getting the right syntax even dont know that this method is right for getting the textbox value by their textchanged event or not.

Comment: `onclick="ShowData(this.value)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
onclick="ShowData('$('#Material_PartNo@(i)').val()')"
```

To

```
onclick="ShowData(this.value)"
```

however I suspect from the classes you are implementing an autocomplete plugin and need to work within the API of that plugin